# CMake - Create multi-config project using existing non multi-config cmake project

Tags: cmake

The dev team had started working with non multi-config CMake, the configuration being defined in the command line (`-D CONFIG=DEBUG` / `-D CONFIG=RELEASE`).

I would like to make a multi-config CMake project (I already know how to make one from scratch).

---

**REQUIREMENTS**:

> I shall not change the original CMake files. At the end I should be able to do `cmake -S CMakeOriginal/ ...` and `cmake -S CMakeNew/ ...`.

> I do not want to just write a new version of the cmake project because if there were changes on the original CMake files, I would have to manually report the changes in the new version.

---

My idea is to add a CMakeLists that would do `set(CONFIG DEBUG)` and then include the original top CMakeLists to generate all targets "as usual" for debug config. From there, I could get target properties, especially `LINK_LIBRARIES` to setup new import targets properties `IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG` and `IMPORTED_IMPLIB_DEBUG`.

After that, the idea is to redo previous step with `set(CONFIG RELEASE)` to set imported targets properties `IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE` and `IMPORTED_IMPLIB_RELEASE` but this will attempt to create targets that already exists : the targets name are not different in DEBUG or RELEASE.

**QUESTIONS:**

- Is it possible to remove/rename a target in cmake?
- It it possible to override target property `LINK_LIBRARIES` set from `target_link_libraries`?
- Is there a way to do what I want just using CMake?

Comment: "Is it possible to remove/rename a target in cmake?" - No, once created, the target cannot be removed. "It it possible to override target property LINK_LIBRARIES set from target_link_libraries?" - You could assign a property `LINK_LIBRARIES` directly, e.g. with [set_property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html) command. "Is there a way to do what I want just using CMake?" - I don't think that you will be able to construct multi-config CMake project by traversing the `CMakeLists.txt` twice.